# I don't want to use @WebServlet in my servlet in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I'm using Eclipse Version: Juno Service Release 1.
When I create servlet, yes, there's a web.xml file. But it will not mapping servlet url automaticlly. Also with the InitParam.

I know that's because of the @WebServlet annotation.

Can I do something to make the Eclipse map the url in web.xml file, not using the @WebServlet annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the *Dynamic Web Module* version back to 2.5 in *Project Facets* section of project's properties.

Comment: if I still use the annotation, it means I needn't deploy the web.xml file any more? So how to make things configurable? Config the param in code??

Comment: @roast_soul . Think of annotations as storing default values. Deployment Descriptors always take preference over annotations. So if you have your Servlet configured with a url mapping as "/" in your annotation and "/servlet" in web.xml, it will to resolve to "/servlet". however if web.xml doesn't exist, then it will resolve to "/".